# How can I set an Element's Id in js by it's name?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set an element's ID by it's name for a loop.

I have Tried to set the Id by calling the element by it's name then setting the id as a string

```
<img name="myFirstImage" src="" id="" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer" 
<script> document.getElementsByName("myFirstImage").id = "imageBox";</script>
```

Please note that I set the img scr to an img by its ID in a loop, so the img displays if I set the image ID manually. The problem is setting the ID by the name of the element. Everything else works.

Comment: Please, note that [getElementByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a `NodeList`, not a single element.

Comment: That selector `document.getElementsByName()` will return a collection (node list) of elements hence getElement**S**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a NodeList. You are trying to change the id of NodeList.
 
You can also you `document.querySelector('img[name="myFirstImage"]')`. This will return single element.

```js
document.getElementsByName("myFirstImage")[0].id = "imageBox";
console.log(document.getElementById('imageBox'));
```

```html
<img name="myFirstImage" src="" id="" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns collection. To access the element you have use proper *index*.

> The [`Document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) method of the Document object returns a *NodeList* Collection of elements with a given name in the document.

```js
document.getElementsByName("myFirstImage")[0].id = "imageBox";
console.log(document.getElementsByName("myFirstImage")[0].id);
```

```html
<img name="myFirstImage" src="/test" id="" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer">
```